# Can mod_cluster work with JBoss AS 4.3?

Tags: jboss, mod-cluster

[mod-cluster main page](http://mod-cluster.jboss.org/) specifies JBoss AS 5 as a minimum requirement for mod_cluster.

But at the same time on [mod-cluster documentation page](http://docs.jboss.org/mod_cluster/1.3.0/html/) we can read how to configure JBoss AS 4.3

Is it some kind of documentation mistake? Anyone runs JBoss AS 4.3 with mod_cluster on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JBoss AS 5 is the oldest JBoss AS with which one could get mod_cluster working without any additional development effort.

mod_cluster is added as a *.sar; suggested version is the latest in mod_cluster 1.0.x branch.

Lemme add that using software as old as this is discouraged; you should move to Wildfly and mod_cluster 1.3.x.